# Excel VBA: <Unable to get the Activate property of the Worksheet class>

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am downloading the xlsm template file to the user. Once the doc is opened after download, getting "Unable to get the Activate property of the Worksheet class" error in the line 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet").Activate' inconsistently. Unable to understand what  am i doing wrong.

My Code is,

```
Sub GetData(hostName As String, id As String)

  'Construct the Complete URL to get the saved view data
  Dim URL As String
  URL = hostName + "/Controller/Action?param=" + id

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet").Activate
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet").Cells.ClearContents

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;" + URL, _
        Destination:=Range("a1")) _
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

Update: Getting this error only for the first time opened after downloading (I am downloading to the user from my app - macro enabled  doc - XLSM ). Once i closed the doc and open again, it is working fine :(

Comment: is the worksheet *DataSheet* visible (not hidden) ?

Comment: Does not activating the Datasheet make a difference?  Can't your first line of the With statement be changed to: **Sheets("DataSheet").QueryTables.Add( _**  I don't see any reason in your code to have to activate it first.

Comment: it's a strange one as **Activate** is a method (such as cell.activate, workbook.activate, range.activate) and AFAIK **Activate** is not a property at all.

Comment: @Santhosh: is the worksheet *DataSheet* protected?

Comment: @sous2817, I want to activate the sheet only if the user is in another sheet and refresh the query... Sothat user can feel that the data refreshed

Comment: @philip, no not a protected sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your code as below:

```
Sub GetData(hostName As String, id As String)

  'Construct the Complete URL to get the saved view data
  Dim URL As String
  URL = hostName + "/Controller/Action?param=" + id

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet").Cells.ClearContents ' leaves formatting

  With Sheets("DataSheet").QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;" + URL, _
        Destination:=Range("a1")) _
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Did almost similar kind of changes and working fine. But the problem is if the user refreshes the data when another sheet is in active, then data refreshes in my sheet but does not activate. How to activate particular sheet using VBA?

Comment: @Santhosh: the best way to get the code for 70% of actions in Excel is to turn on the macro recorder then carry out the actions, and look at the code. To answer your question, it's similar to your *original code*, use the **Select** method on the **Worksheet** (though **Activate** should work unless the sheet is a *Chartsheet*)